how can i display a fragment on a floating window using a button that is on another fragment
i try to go from one fragment to another within the floating window using buttons. I manage the fragments using a activity that contains them but when using the button on the first fragment (Ubicacion1Fragment.java) it displays a blank view with nothing on it and it is imposible to go back using the back button buit on the phone.
I tried using the logs to see the problem but i am not able to see any of the logs i wrote on the logcat.
The floating window is setup as a service FloatingWindowService.java and i have a class that manages the service FloatingWindowGFG.java this service and the class that manages the services i copied from this web https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-make-a-floating-window-application-in-android/ and im trying to change it to my needs.
Sorry if i explin it wrong english is not my first lenguage.
FloatingWindowService.java
package com.tfg.ayuda;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi;

public class FloatingWindowService extends Service {
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private View popupView;

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d("FloatingWindowService", "Service created");

        if (!Settings.canDrawOverlays(this)) {
            Log.e("FloatingWindowService", "Overlay permission not granted");
            stopSelf();
            return;
        }

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        popupView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_whatsapp, null);

        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 0;

        windowManager.addView(popupView, params);
        Log.d("FloatingWindowService", "Popup view added to window manager");
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("FloatingWindowService", "Service started");
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (popupView != null) {
            windowManager.removeView(popupView);
            popupView = null;
        }
        Log.d("FloatingWindowService", "Service destroyed and view removed");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }
}

FloatingWindowGFG.java
package com.tfg.ayuda;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.DisplayMetrics;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.annotation.Nullable;

public class FloatingWindowGFG extends Service {

    private ViewGroup floatView;
    private WindowManager.LayoutParams floatWindowLayoutParam;
    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private String fragmentType; // Para saber qué fragmento inflar

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        // Calcular el tamaño de la pantalla
        DisplayMetrics metrics = getApplicationContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
        int width = metrics.widthPixels;
        int height = metrics.heightPixels;

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getBaseContext().getSystemService(LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        // Inflar el diseño basado en el fragmento
        if ("UBICACION1".equals(fragmentType)) {
            floatView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ubicacion1, null);
        } else if ("UBICACION2".equals(fragmentType)) {
            floatView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ubicacion2, null);
        } else {
            // Manejar el caso cuando el tipo de fragmento es desconocido
            floatView = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ubicacion1, null); // Predeterminado
        }

        Button maximizeBtn = floatView.findViewById(R.id.siguienteUbicacion1);

        int LAYOUT_TYPE;
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            LAYOUT_TYPE = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_APPLICATION_OVERLAY;
        } else {
            LAYOUT_TYPE = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_TOAST;
        }

        floatWindowLayoutParam = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                (int) (width * (0.80f)),
                (int) (height * (0.30f)),
                LAYOUT_TYPE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT
        );

        floatWindowLayoutParam.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
        floatWindowLayoutParam.x = 0;
        floatWindowLayoutParam.y = 0;

        windowManager.addView(floatView, floatWindowLayoutParam);

        maximizeBtn.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            stopSelf();
            windowManager.removeView(floatView);
            Intent activityIntent = new Intent(FloatingWindowGFG.this, FragmentContainerActivity.class);
            activityIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
            startActivity(activityIntent);
        });

        floatView.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            final WindowManager.LayoutParams floatWindowLayoutUpdateParam = floatWindowLayoutParam;
            double x;
            double y;
            double px;
            double py;

            @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        x = floatWindowLayoutUpdateParam.x;
                        y = floatWindowLayoutUpdateParam.y;
                        px = event.getRawX();
                        py = event.getRawY();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        floatWindowLayoutUpdateParam.x = (int) ((x + event.getRawX()) - px);
                        floatWindowLayoutUpdateParam.y = (int) ((y + event.getRawY()) - py);
                        windowManager.updateViewLayout(floatView, floatWindowLayoutUpdateParam);
                        break;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        // Obtener el tipo de fragmento desde el Intent
        if (intent != null) {
            fragmentType = intent.getStringExtra("FRAGMENT_TYPE");
        }

        // Continuar con la creación de la ventana flotante
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        stopSelf();
        if (floatView != null) {
            windowManager.removeView(floatView);
        }
    }
}

Ubicacion1Fragment.java
package com.tfg.ayuda;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;

import android.util.Log;


public class Ubicacion1Fragment extends Fragment {

    public Ubicacion1Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ubicacion1, container, false);

        Button buttonToSecondFragment = view.findViewById(R.id.siguienteUbicacion1);
        Log.d("Ubicacion1Fragment", "onCreateView: Button to second fragment found.");
        buttonToSecondFragment.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getParentFragmentManager();  // Use getParentFragmentManager instead of getChildFragmentManager
            Ubicacion2Fragment ubicacion2Fragment = new Ubicacion2Fragment();
            Log.d("Ubicacion1Fragment", "onCreateView: Navigating to Ubicacion2Fragment");
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                    .replace(R.id.fragment_container, ubicacion2Fragment)
                    .addToBackStack(null)
                    .commit();
        });
        Log.d("Ubicacion1Fragment", "onCreateView: Ubicacion1Fragment created successfully.");
        return view;
    }
}

Ubicacion2Fragment.java
package com.tfg.ayuda;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;



public class Ubicacion2Fragment extends Fragment {

    public Ubicacion2Fragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_ubicacion2, container, false);

        return view;
    }
}

i tried looking for an error there was none, then the logs and i could not find them on the logcat, then i tried to see if there was any spelling mistake or if the id where duplicate but no and i dont know what else to look for
